# How can we provide square brackets under regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have an api which accepts PIN which shouldnt be anything other than numeric. I am using regex to check if the pin contains any other character. This is my regex

```
var regex = new Regex("[a-zA-Z!@#$&(){}%^*_=;:?<>\\-`.+,/\"]");
```

I need to add verification for [] brackets also but whenever i put it inside the expression it doesn't work.

```
var regex = new Regex("[a-zA-Z!@#$&(){}%^*_=;:?<>[]\\-`.+,/\"]");
```

Do i need to use any special character for this ?

Comment: AFAIR, you need to escape them using \, just like you did for `"`.

Comment: There are many characters that are neither digits nor in your regex - why not just use `[0-9]` to match only digits? Or if you want to match invalid characters, use `[^0-9]` to match everything except those.

Comment: Escape `]` as you escaped the hyphen.

Comment: @Saud No need escaping `/` anywhere inside a .NET pattern, it is not a special char. Your suggestion is wrong, you escaped `[`  that does not need escaping inside a character class, you should have escaped `]`. Well, if you tried your suggestion in code, you would get another syntax issue here, too.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew StribiżewWoops! Confused it with PCRE. My bad.
I've deleted my comment

Comment: The solution is `"[][a-zA-Z!@#$&(){}%^*_=;:?<>\`.+,/\"-]"`